# Convert an XML file containing a SOAP message to a string and update values of particular tags

Tags: java, xml, xpath, soap

So i wanted to see if there was a way to convert an XML file with a soap message to a string and then update the values of particular tags. Here are the tags that i am talking about.

```
 <o:Username>Bill</o:Username>
 <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Hello123</o:Password>
```

What i had originally done was update the xml file itself with the new user and pass, as seen in the code below.

```
try {
        String namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
        configProperties.load(SecurityTokenHandler.class.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE));
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document requestDoc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(SecurityTokenHandler.class.getResourceAsStream(SOAP_REQUEST_FILE));
        Element docElement = requestDoc.getDocumentElement();
        docElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, "Username").item(0).setTextContent(configProperties.getProperty("username"));
        docElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace,"Password").item(0).setTextContent(configProperties.getProperty("password"));
        Transformer docTransformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(requestDoc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(SecurityTokenHandler.class.getResource(SOAP_REQUEST_FILE).getFile());
        docTransformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch(IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | TransformerException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("There was an error loading the properties file", exception);
    }
```

However, i found out later on that as this is a resource file, i'm not allowed to modify the file itself. I have to store the xml file as a string, update the user and password values without modifying the file, and then return a byte array of the xml file with the updated values (without modifying the original document). Any idea how i can accomplish this?

Comment: @aUserHimself Any clues?

Comment: How about using an XSLT transformation? Looks like it would be a simple transformation. If you think that's an option, please rephrase the question as follows: show a complete XML input file and the output XML file you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution i came up with was to basically change the result to a byteArrayOuputStream rather than the xml file itself. Posting updated code:

```
try {
        String namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
        configProperties.load(SecurityTokenHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE));
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document requestDoc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(SecurityTokenHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(SOAP_REQUEST_FILE));
        Element docElement = requestDoc.getDocumentElement();
        docElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, "Username").item(0).setTextContent(configProperties.getProperty("username"));
        docElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace,"Password").item(0).setTextContent(configProperties.getProperty("password"));
        Transformer docTransformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(byteArrayOutputStream);
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(requestDoc);
            docTransformer.transform(source, result);
            b = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }
    } catch(IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | TransformerException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("There was an error loading the properties file", exception);
    }
```